# ngRoute reference error

Tags: html, angularjs

As shown I'm attempting to use a controller to retrieve a JSON file,But the error

> "Failed to instantiate module getJson due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=get..."

Keep popping up. I have already referenced the angular dependency ngRoute here.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../public/javascripts/processJson.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
   <div ng-app="getJson"><div ng-controller="controller1">
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
       <div ng-switch-when="text"><input type="text" id="{{post.id}}" ng-model="post.value" placeholder="{{post.placeholder}}">
 </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Controller**

```
var getJson = angular.module('getJson', []).controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http) {
var url = "../../routes/fields.js";
console.log(url);
$http.get(url).success(function (data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  });

 });
```

Comment: you should use angular-route.js minified version as you are using angular lib in minified version

Comment: Using minified file or un-minified has got nothing to do with the error. @RIYAJKHAN

Answer (score 0):

You have added the angular-route file but you have not added it as a dependency in your module.
Please use

```
var getJson = angular.module('getJson', ['ngRoute']).controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http) {
var url = "../../routes/fields.js";
console.log(url);
$http.get(url).success(function (data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
  });

 });
```